# parar un setinterval al presionar un botón

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de parar este contador al hacer click en el boton stop, sin embargo no se como limpiar el intervalo ya que esta dentro de la funcion timer.

Gracias por la ayuda

```js
 var stop = document.getElementById("stop");
 
 
              var seconds = 0;
              var minutes = 0
              var hours = 0;
            function timer(){
                let counting = setInterval(function(){
                    if(seconds == 60){
                        minutes++
                        console.log(minutes);
                        seconds = 0;
                        if(minutes == 60){
                            minutes = 00;
                            hours++
                            console.log(hours);
                        }
                    }
                    seconds++;
                    console.log(seconds);
                    
                    
                    }, 1000);
            } 

            timer();
            
            
   stop.addEventListener("click", function(){
      clearInterval(counting);
   });
```

```html
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te ha olvidado que let tiene un `ambito` de tipo bloque, en pocas palabras, solo existe dentro de tu función `timer` por que ahí la declaras, pero no fuera de ahí.

Para solucionarlo solo debes inicializar tu variable por fuera de la función y dentro de esta setear el setInterval:

```js
var stop = document.getElementById("stop");
 
 
              var seconds = 0;
              var minutes = 0
              var hours = 0;
              //Declaramos a counting afuera...
              let counting;
            function timer(){
                counting = setInterval(function(){
                    if(seconds == 60){
                        minutes++
                        console.log(minutes);
                        seconds = 0;
                        if(minutes == 60){
                            minutes = 00;
                            hours++
                            console.log(hours);
                        }
                    }
                    seconds++;
                    console.log(seconds);
                    
                    
                    }, 1000);
            } 

            timer();
            
            
   stop.addEventListener("click", function(){
      clearInterval(counting);
   });
```

```html
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Recordemos que var crea una referencia global que puede ser usada en cualquier parte siempre y cuando el código que la use haga uso de ella cuando esta ya este creada.

Mientras que `let` y `const` solo existiran dentro del bloque donde las hayas definido, donde un bloque consiste en cualquier cosa que este delimitada por llaves `{}`.