# Detener y continuar setInterval con un solo botón

Tags: botón, setinterval

Buscando entre las preguntas no encuentro mi repuesta y por eso pido un poco de ayuda.
Cada página html5 que tengo independientemente  funciona con sus setInterval.
Al terminar el vídeo muestra un div con el siguiente vídeo y un botón para detener el setInterval. Funciona la detención pero no puedo lograr reanudar el setInterval para que siga la cuenta regresiva.

```
var seguir = false;
var boton = false;
function cancelar() {
if (!seguir) {
fin = 
clearInterval(yo);
ó.innerHTML = "siguiente..?"; 


 $(".regresiva").css({'backgroun d': 'rgba(128,0,0, .7)'});    
seguir = true; 
    localStorage.setItem('boton', true);
 }
else {
        fin = window.clearTimeout(fin);

        ó.innerHTML = "ó cancelar"; 
        $(".regresiva").css({'background': 'rgba(0,128,0, .3)'});  
        seguir = false;
        localStorage.setItem('boton', false);  
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [parar un setinterval al presionar un botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351067/parar-un-setinterval-al-presionar-un-bot%c3%b3n)

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿deseas *pausar* un `setInterval` o detener la ejecución del mismo? Lo segundo es fácil con `clearInterval()`, pero lo primero no lo veo tan claro. Me parece que lo que buscas es evaluar una condición durante la ejecución del `setInterval`. Pero sin saber exactamente el propósito de lo que intentas hacer es difícil responderte. Saludos

Comment: En realidad el botón cumple dos funciones: (da lo mismo pausar o detener si es posible) al presionar el botón trato de detener el contador y al mismo tiempo guardar en LocalStorage. Luego presiono y continua el contador dejando activo. Es lo mismo que activar y desactivar siguiente vídeo

Comment: Sigo sin entender, por favor edita tu pregunta y aclara un poco más el propósito de tu código. ¿Cuál contador? En tu código no se ve ninguna variable que cumpla un rol de contador. ¿Qué guardas en el `localStorage`. En tu código se ve que guardas un ¿booleano?. Hablas de un video pero en tu código no veo nada relacionado con dicho elemento. En fin, tal como está redactada tu pregunta y tu comentario me es difícil entenderlo. Saludos